# how to make virtual directory to root

Tags: asp.net

I have a project in which in a number of pages the page redirecting code is written like

**Response.Redirect(~/pagename);**

Now at hosting server, its working fine as its a root directory

but on my testing server, we have created a virtual directory such as Site1

now i have to map it like

Response.Redirect(~/Site1/pagename);

then page is being open

is there any way through webcofig, or global.asax or any other way we can tell site to treat ~/(root) as ~/site

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In IIS right click on 'Sites' and select 'Add Web Site'. Then set the path to site1 as the root of the new web site. Set the bindings to something like port 81 so that you can access it at the same time as your default site.

Comment: If you don't have access, ask your network people to set it up. This is the correct way to do it. What you're asking for in with mapping multiple root folders doesn't really make sense.